# Grails form submit populates an Integer field with a String

Tags: forms, grails, groovy

I have a map that takes an Integer as its key but when my form is submitted, that key becomes a String.

1) I don't even understand how that's possible.  My map explicitly states that only Integers can be keys, yet its being populated with strings?  Probably just some Groovy thing...

2) Assuming #1 is just weird some groovy thing, how can I force my `questions` map keySet to be populated with Integers like i want it to instead of Strings?

```
class ApplicationCommand implements Validateable {
    Map<Integer,String[]> questions = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String[]>();
}

<g:textField name="cmd.questions[14]" value="${cmd.questions[14][0]}" />

def save(ApplicationCommand cmd) {
    System.out.println(cmd.questions.containsKey(14));  //FALSE
    System.out.println(cmd.questions.containsKey("14"));  //TRUE

    ....
}
```

EDIT: Grails 3.1

Comment: shouldn't the textField name be just "questions[14]" instead of "cmd.questions[14]" ?  btw, which grails version ?

Comment: @aldrin if I don't add `cmd` then my command object doesn't get populated at all.  Grails 3.1, i updated my OP with that info.

Comment: it works as expected in Grails 2.x, so they must have changed something in 3. Definitely feels odd and might be a bug.

Comment: @aldrin maybe, I don't know.  So many things about Grails don't feel right to be but turns out that its by design so I don't question it anymore, I just figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a [GrailsParameterMap](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsParameterMap.html) and call the methods explicitly like:

```
map.getInt(key)
```

I'm not sure of a better way, offhand. This class is also very helpful when submitting multiple values of the same name that should be interpreted as a list.